# DNN Only Google Login provider

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is it possible that you configure dnn (9.1.1) that way that you can sign in and login only with google account.

I know that at start I need to create host user at installation,
then I know that I can enable google login provider, but don't know how
then I can force only google logins and registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with custom CSS:

```
.LoginPanel{
  display:none;
}
.registerGroup{
  display:none !important;
}
```

Then I also add a module visible for registered users on all pages with code:

```
<style type="text/css">.registerGroup{
  display:inline-block !important;
}
```

I know it is "dirty" and not secure but it was an easy solution for my needs,
you still can display controls with developer tools and register with username and password...

But for now I am OK with this...